# Would a second controller improve organisation of a long form in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## What I am trying to do

I am using the simple form gem. My form has about 50 questions and inputs. The questions are related to health such as "have you ever been prescribed medication for XXX ?". Some questions like this one have related fields such as, "date", "type of medicine", "I am currently taking/I took this in the past". This type of question is the hardest because it must be in a table layout and the person can enter multiple medications. I will put five blank lines, but ideally I would like to let the user add as many as is needed.

When I started creating the form, I had envisaged a short form with simple fields (`name:string, age:integer, weight:decimal, sex:boolean`, etc.), but the form quickly became too large and long to manage in this way.

## How I have implemented it so far

I currently have only the `Questionnaire` controller. I created a cut down test version of the form. Below are the files relevant to this test form. Here is the form partial `_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@questionnaire) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :dob %>
    <%= f.input :q1 %>
    <%= f.input :q2 %>
    <%= f.input :q3 %>
#3 fields below are causing the problems (q4, q5, q6)
    <%= f.input :q4 %>
    <%= f.input :q5 %>
    <%= f.input :q6 %>

    <%= f.input :q7 %>
    <%= f.input :q8 %>
    <%= f.input :q9 %>
    <%= f.input :q10 %>
    <%= f.input :q11 %>
    <%= f.input :q12 %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

`schema.rb`

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180516082217) do

  create_table "questionnaires", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.date "dob"
    t.string "q1"
    t.string "q2"
    t.string "q3"
    t.text "q4"
    t.text "q5"
    t.text "q6"
    t.boolean "q7"
    t.boolean "q8"
    t.boolean "q9"
    t.integer "q10"
    t.integer "q11"
    t.integer "q12"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

The `Questionnaires` controller is simply generated by a scaffold:

```
class QuestionnairesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_questionnaire, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /questionnaires
  # GET /questionnaires.json
  def index
    @questionnaires = Questionnaire.all
  end

  # GET /questionnaires/1
  # GET /questionnaires/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /questionnaires/new
  def new
    @questionnaire = Questionnaire.new
  end

  # GET /questionnaires/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /questionnaires
  # POST /questionnaires.json
  def create
    @questionnaire = Questionnaire.new(questionnaire_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @questionnaire.save
        format.html { redirect_to @questionnaire, notice: 'Questionnaire was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @questionnaire }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @questionnaire.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /questionnaires/1
  # PATCH/PUT /questionnaires/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @questionnaire.update(questionnaire_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @questionnaire, notice: 'Questionnaire was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @questionnaire }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @questionnaire.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /questionnaires/1
  # DELETE /questionnaires/1.json
  def destroy
    @questionnaire.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to questionnaires_url, notice: 'Questionnaire was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_questionnaire
      @questionnaire = Questionnaire.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def questionnaire_params
      params.require(:questionnaire).permit(:name, :dob, :q1, :q2, :q3, :q4, :q5, :q6, :q7, :q8, :q9, :q10, :q11, :q12)
    end
end
```

## Problems

I have problems scaling it to a larger form, longer questions, and more complex relationships between the questions.

### Problem 1

The short names `q1`, `q2`, `q3`, ... show up as the titles to the columns in the show view. In order to change this, I will have to copy and paste each question separately into the heading. I think this is a waste of time and could be automated with ruby code. I am currently using the `label` function to display the questions.

### Problem 2

Some columns need to have the same name, i.e. date, from/to with multiple lines. For example, a person takes only one type of medication versus another one who takes five types. The person with five types with have 5x as many rows in that column field to fill out.

## My solution

I may have the `Questions` controller, where I or an admin can add questions. Then each field would be a string. Then there would be a second controller, maybe an `Answers` controller, where the question part to the input field would be the individual questions from the `Questions` controller. The `Answers` controller would then handle the answers inputter by the users and save so that the show view for each individual `Questionnaire` would have the questions from the `Questions` controller as the headings to the columns and then the answers from the `Answers` controller below.

## Questions

- Am I visualizing this in the correct Rails way?
- Is there a better way to organize this long form?
- Are two controllers needed, or maybe three, or more?
- How do I deal with multiple and changing numbers of inputs (i.e., if one person is taking one type of medication and another needs to enter, say, five types)?
- If my two-controller idea is the way to go, how do I go about joining them so that they can communicate? (`has_many`/`belongs_to` relationships etc.)

Comment: I would review the model. Maybe with Questionnaire, Question, something like [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association).

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good UX to include too many fields on one page. Use a multi-step form https://medium.com/@nicolasblanco/developing-a-wizard-or-multi-steps-forms-in-rails-d2f3b7c692ce

First, you need to design a data model that satisfies the requirements. Suggest the following models:

1. Category: type(expected response type) - pick list, text, array of text, boolean, date etc.
2. Question: Sequence Number(order for questions), category_id, title etc. Also include options(an array of options for pick list type of question).
3. Patient: name etc.
4. Response(Answer): patient_id, question_id, response(text/json or one for each)

For dynamic list(ex: medications taking), provide a +BUTTON and use javascript to add a new input field.

Please treat the above as an high level approach rather than a detailed solution.